# Create a dataframe with all the results from a simple linear regression on multiple data series

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a database in which I'm comparing the habituation rates of crabs across a period of time. I want to create a linear regression for each individual and then gather all the results (intercept, slope and R^2 values) into a dataframe that would look like:

1st Column: Crab ID

2nd Column: Intercept

3rd Column: Slope

4th Column: R^2

My database looks similar to this, but with much more datapoints (132 flips per individual, over 50 individuals)

```
ID  Enclosure   Flip Num    Time taken
2   Simple        1            0.5
2   Simple        2            0.8
2   Simple        3            0.41
2   Simple        4            0.44
4   Bare          1            0.37
4   Bare          2            0.41
4   Bare          3            1.06
4   Bare          4            0.59
5   Simple        1            1.88
5   Simple        2            1.88
5   Simple        3            2.04
5   Simple        4            2.66
6   Complex       1            1.87
6   Complex       2            1.96
6   Complex       3            1.56
6   Complex       4            2.34
9   Complex       1            0.44
9   Complex       2            2.35
9   Complex       3            2.22
9   Complex       4            3.22
```

I found this code on another question, but this only brought back the intercept and slope:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(test, "individual", function(x) {
  model <- lm(condition ~ day, data = x)
  coef(model)
})
```

Comment: Your dataset example and the code is not in sync with different column names

Comment: Have a look at the [broom package](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html)

Answer (score 0):

use `split` and `sapply` as follows. As mentioned in comments the dataset and your code have different columns. For this example I choose two of the columns, to generate the model.

generate data

```
str <- 'ID   Enclosure   FlipNum    Timetaken
2   Simple  1   0.5
2   Simple  2   0.8
2   Simple  3   0.41
2   Simple  4   0.44
4   Bare    1   0.37
4   Bare    2   0.41
4   Bare    3   1.06
4   Bare    4   0.59
5   Simple  1   1.88
5   Simple  2   1.88
5   Simple  3   2.04
5   Simple  4   2.66
6   Complex 1   1.87
6   Complex 2   1.96
6   Complex 3   1.56
6   Complex 4   2.34
9   Complex 1   .44
9   Complex 2   2.35
9   Complex 3   2.22
9   Complex 4   3.22'



file <- textConnection(str)
df <- read.table(file, header = T)

df
```

get all coefficients

```
sapply(split(df, df$ID),function(x) {
  model <- lm(Timetaken ~ FlipNum, data = x)
  c(ID = x$ID[1],coef(model),R2 = summary(model)[['r.squared']])
})
```

result:

```
                     2         4         5         6         9
ID           2.0000000 4.0000000 5.0000000 6.0000000 9.0000000
(Intercept)  0.6800000 0.2800000 1.4900000 1.6800000 0.0050000
FlipNum     -0.0570000 0.1310000 0.2500000 0.1010000 0.8210000
R2           0.1690867 0.2855645 0.7564754 0.1648114 0.8260964
```